# Should tables have variables in columns or rows?

Tags: research-process, writing-style

Should tables in scientific research have each independent and dependent variable be constrained to a column or a row?

Comment: Wouldn't BOTH columns and rows (unless of length one) depict **variable elements** (numbers, names of months, variable descriptive terms, algebraic expressions, etc.)? My guess is that you mean something more specific by "variable" (perhaps independent variable?) -- you should include this additional specificity in your question.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro i edited it but i don't know if that is much clearer...

Answer (score 2):

Wrong question. The right question is: How do I present data in such a way that it is easiest to understand for my readers. *Rules* for presentation are always superseded by aiming to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Which is the easiest to understand out of e.g. "time" being a column or row? Doesn't ease of understanding depend on familiarity?

Comment: Yes. And what is familiar depends on context -- context only you can know as the expert in the field. For example, in most disciplines, distance is typically shown on the horizontal axis, growing to the right. In geophysics, depth (a distance) is shown on the vertical axis, growing downward. That makes sense in that context. But what is right for you is something only you can determine.